# emacs 終了時に聞かれる、「変更があるけれども大丈夫？」のファイル一覧を取得したい。

Tags: emacs

ファイルを編集して保存していない際に、 emacs 終了時に、"Save file XXXXXX (OPTIONS)" が表示されます。これをひとつひとつ表示されて、それについて保存する・しないを確認するよりは、「このリストをあらかじめ一覧的に確認して、必要に応じてそのまま kill したい」と考えました。

### 質問

終了時などに「保存しますか？」と聞かれるファイル（を visit しているバッファ）を一覧して必要に応じて各種操作(最低その buffer を選択)することはできますか？

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでしょうか。

```
(defun user/buffer-needs-save-p (buffer)
  "Return non-nil if the visited-file BUFFER is still modified."
  (and (buffer-file-name buffer)
       (buffer-modified-p buffer)))

;; 未保存のバッファに対して処理を行う
(dolist (b (buffer-list))
  (when (user/buffer-needs-save-p b)
    ...))
```

Emacsのソースコード([1](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-25/src/buffer.c#L1665),[2](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-25/lisp/files.el#L6675))を眺めるに、「保存の必要があるバッファかどうか」を調べる関数等はelispでは提供されていないように見えたので自作しています。

Answer (score 0):

@kosh さんの回答を参考に、「一覧表示」をしてみると次になりました。 (keybind が多少いけていないけれども、ひとまず。)

```
(defun user/buffer-needs-save-p (buffer)
  "Return non-nil if the visited-file BUFFER is still modified."
  (and (buffer-file-name buffer)
       (buffer-modified-p buffer)))

;; 未保存のバッファに対して処理を行う

(defun modified-buffer-list ()
  (interactive)
  (let (ret)
    (dolist (b (buffer-list))
      (when (user/buffer-needs-save-p b)
        (setq ret (cons b ret))))
    (switch-to-buffer (list-buffers-noselect nil ret))))
```